# Having a bit of an issue installing dlib on Windows

Tags: python, windows, opencv, dlib

```
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Jehad/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-uz9hgn/dlib/build/temp.win32-2.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/Jehad/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-uz9hgn/dlib/build/temp.win32-2.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\jehad\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uz9hgn\dlib\setup.py", line 238, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\jehad\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uz9hgn\dlib\setup.py", line 119, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "c:\users\jehad\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uz9hgn\dlib\setup.py", line 153, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'c:\\users\\jehad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uz9hgn\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=c:\\users\\jehad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uz9hgn\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-2.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\python27\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=c:\\users\\jehad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uz9hgn\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-2.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\jehad\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-uz9hgn\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jehad\appdata\local\temp\pip-xb26oy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jehad\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uz9hgn\dlib\
```

---

I have been trying to install dlib in my windows pc, but it showed it dint have cmake so after pip install cmake, it shows this error.

I am quite new to this, so like still trying to understand what this error means and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Install CMake using the installer from cmake.org. And make sure you tell the installer to put it into your path.